# Program using java runs on root fine, but errors with user

Tags: command-line, java, root, openjdk

I have a shell script that loads a jar file. When executed with sudo, it loads. However, when not using sudo, I get errors and it will not load.

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

jversion=$(java -version 2>&1 | grep -i version)

if [ -z "$jversion" ]; then
    echo "This software is built using Java technology,"
    echo "so please take a moment to install Java to be able to use the software on your computer."
    echo ""
    exit 1
fi

jv=$(java -version 2>&1 | grep -i version | cut -d'"' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1-2)

if [ $jv == "1.6" ] || [ $jv == "1.7" ]; then
    echo "Your version of Java is not supported."
    echo "Please update your Java to version 1.8 to be able to use the software on your computer."
    exit 1
fi

java -Duser.dir=/opt/link-assistantcom/ranktracker/resources/ \
     -Xms64m \
     -Xmx768m \
     -Xss1024k \
     -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot \
     -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
     -jar /opt/link-assistantcom/ranktracker/bin/ranktracker.jar
```

I had to cut the error code out for this to post.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing the error, not much we can do.

Comment: `/opt/` is owned by `root`.... Thus the need for `sudo`. Place the jar file in your home directory under the ownership of your current user and change its path in your script accordingly and it should load without `sudo`

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: @Raffa Could you please take what you wrote as a comment and post that as an answer below for Richard to accept?

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat added an answer for posterity. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the jar file you are trying to run is located under `/opt/`.

`/opt/` is owned by root.... Thus the need for `sudo`.

To solve this, place the jar file in your home directory under the ownership of your current user and change its path in your script accordingly and it should load without `sudo`.